AWS Lambda getting triggered more than once
I have created a lambda which trigger a DAG when a file is uploaded to a specific S3 bucket.
Once I upload the file in the S3 bucket, the lambda triggers the DAG and the DAG runs. But while the DAG is running and processing the file uploaded, sometimes the lambda again triggers the same DAG even if no new file uploaded to the bucket.
Below is the trigger configuration for S3:
Bucket arn: arn:aws:s3:::abhi-dev-backup
Event types: s3:ObjectCreated:Post, s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload
isComplexStatement: No
Prefix: com/source/trade/out/

Below is the lambda code:
import json
import boto3
import io
import http.client
import base64
import ast

s3Client = boto3.client('s3')
client = boto3.client('mwaa')
#s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

mwaa_env_name = 'dev-airflow'
mwaa_cli_command = 'dags trigger '


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dag_name = ''
    #Get bucket and file name
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_path = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    file_name = file_path.split('/').pop()
    
    print('Bucket Name:'+bucket_name)
    print('File Path:'+file_path)
    print('File Name:'+file_name)
    
    if "SAMPLE_FILE_REQ" in file_name:
        dag_name = 'FILE_REQ_DAG'
        print('DAG NAME:'+dag_name)
    elif "SAMPLE_IMAGE_REQ" in file_name:
        dag_name = 'IMAGE_REQ_DAG'
        print('DAG NAME:'+dag_name)
    
    
    # get web token
    mwaa_cli_token = client.create_cli_token(
        Name=mwaa_env_name
    )
    if dag_name != '':
        #print(mwaa_cli_token)
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(mwaa_cli_token['WebServerHostname'])
        payload = mwaa_cli_command + dag_name
        #print(payload)
        headers = {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + mwaa_cli_token['CliToken'],
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        }
        conn.request("POST", "/aws_mwaa/cli", payload, headers)
        print('Request sent!')
        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()
        dict_str = data.decode("UTF-8")
        mydata = ast.literal_eval(dict_str)
    else:
        print('No DAG to run');

Where am I making wrong? Why the lambda executes more than once even when file is uploaded only once?

you could log the event details (esp. eventName) to figure out what it is. See more info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html#with-s3-example-test-dummy-event

Note that an S3 event that triggers a Lambda function is an asynchronous invocation. The Lambda service will retry this invocation if it fails or times out.

I was able to fix it by increasing the timeout of the lambda configuration from 3 secs to 10 secs.
